# Installing The Hessling Editor (THE) and Locating the Demonstration File

Tags: software-installation, editors

I'm still getting started with Linux. I've been trying to install The Hessling Editor with REXX enabled on Ubuntu (and hopefully the Linux Subsystem on Windows in the future). I thought it would be simple by just doing

```
sudo apt-get install the
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install regina-rexx
```

but then I'm not able to find the demonstration file. I've tried searching for it

```
find options ./ "demo.the"
```

but the search yields nothing. Am I doing something wrong or do I need to get the demonstration file from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is in `/usr/share/THE`.

You can find this by running `dpkg -L the | grep demo.the`, or if you install `apt-file`, `apt-file search demo.the`. You can also use `find`, as you thought, as follows:

```
find / -name demo.the
```

This starts searching from the root directory, looking for a file named `demo.the`. You’ll get a lot of error messages saying you don’t have the necessary permissions to access certain directories, but it will still find the file.

Comment: Was I using the command `find` incorrectly?